# Why is setState not re-rendering the App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display a value stored in memory using a Text component in React Native. Storing and reading work fine, I can get proper values in console. I get values and setState with them.

```
getData = async (key) => {
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@"+key);
  return value != null ? JSON.parse(value) : null;
} catch(e) {
  // error screen
}
}

// ... some code here (btw its all inside of the class App)

fetchData = async () => {
this.setState({
  role: await this.getData("role"),
  calls_version: await this.getData("v_calls")
});
}

_ = this.fetchData();  // calling this to run fetchData function

splashScreen = () => {
return (
  <View style={ styles.splash_screen }>
    <Image style={ styles.splash_image } source={{ uri: "..." }}/>
    <Text style={ styles.splash_text }>{ this.state.role }</Text>
  </View>
);
}

render() {
return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Splash" component={ this.splashScreen } />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
}
```

But when I run this, nothing happens.
If this can help, here is the sequence of this.state.role values:

1. undefined in render()
2. undefined in splashScreen()
3. "proper value" in render()
4. fetchData() completed

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `_ = this.fetchData();` some weird way to try and do something when the component is mounting? Why not just use `componentDidMount`? I don't think this is a direct issue, but try awaiting the asyncStorage fetches *then* enqueue the state update.